# how to get a list( as a value) from dictionay using C#

Tags: c#

Dictionary have a List as a value.

I want to get that List from dictionary.

Eg: Dictionary(boolean, List) dic =new Dictionary(boolean, List)();

get a list from dic.

Comment: Your question is *incredibly* vague. It's impossible to answer it without you providing more details - ideally code.

Comment: Why would you want a dictionary keyed by a boolean? Given that booleans have exactly two possible values and dictionary keys must be unique you'd only ever be able to add two lists to your dictionary...

Answer (score 2):

use

```
List list = dictionary[<key>];
```

where  is the key that was used to store the list.

Or do you mean you want the list of all values that the dictionary has?  In which case you want something like:

```
IList list=new ArrayList (dictionary.Values);
```

given your updated question if you have a dictionary which has 2 lists keyed by a bool then you just want to do:

```
List list = dictionary[true];
```

or

```
List list = dictionary[false];
```

Comment: +1 for the "IList list=new ArrayList (dictionary.Values);" answer

Answer (score 1):

First you need to add a list to your dictionary

```
var boolListDict = new Dictionary<bool, List>()

boolListDict[true] = new List();
```

then you can retrieve the list like so:

```
List truelist = boolListDict[true];
```